# Searching by several columns in diffrent tables using one input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I know that this question or its variations were discussed many times.
But I didn't find exactly my solution.

I have many tables assume **10**. I would like to provide a solution for searching in **table1.field1**, **table2.field2**, ... **table10.field10** using only one form input field. When User is typing a searching phrase Autocomplete field have to suggest a list of available results with note a table its goes from.

First idea that comes in my mind is denormalization i.e. creation a separate table **Table_for_search(field1, ..., field10)** that contains data from tables was mentioned above.

My problem is I wouldn't like to use any heavy solutions like Sphinx, ElasticSearch etc. Also light solutions like **meta_search.gem**, **ransack.gem** look like not suitable for may situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does ten tables have relationship?

Comment: Maybe freetext search, if using postgres it is built in. Other options : http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=30

Comment: @anonymousxxx, yes and no at the same time. table1 has associations with table3, table2 with table4 and so on.